# Is it possible to turn on/off notification from different applications on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am working on an application that will allow the user to turn off cellular data or at least turn off notifications from other applications on the device, all through my application. Is this possible? (I know that in Android it possible)

Answer (score 4):

Your app has absolutely no control what-so-ever of other apps, not even indirectly.  The **one** exception is using a custom url scheme to open the app, and optionally, ask it to do something.

Comment: The same probably also applies to "turn off cellular data". Or can an app do that?

Comment: @Thilo Nope, can't even do that. 3rd Party iOS apps are for the most part in a sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

No, on iOS you can't even find what other apps the user has installed.

Even if you could, they are all sandboxed. You can't touch anything inside the other apps.